# Can anyone provide an example about two-way data binding in react?

Tags: reactjs, two-way-binding

I saw many videos related to two-way data binding in react, but, I didn't get the idea about why even we need it.

Is it something very important to use two-way data binding in react, I even developed projects using react but I don't think that it's something important. I know that it's something used in Angular by using ngModel!!

Comment: The concept doesn't apply: React (and Redux, from which React is derived from) is based on a strict one-way flow of data, not two-way. Whereas Angular is about stateful components with no hard rules about where state lives or how it should be updated (but most Angular applications I've seen just mutate state in-place, but you _can_ use Redux with Angular if you're feeling brave).

Comment: So, can I say that using two-way is not meant for react ?

Comment: Yes-and-no. It's possible that when people say "two-way binding" they _really mean_ "implementing two-way data-binding in React **via** React's one-way flow of data".

Comment: In angular's two way binding, it provides a way to change a variable and have it propagate to some component change.  React does not have this facility and similar awareness of state is done through the `useState` hook which gives a pair of state value and function to set state.  The equivalent of two way binding is by combining setting the state with whatever action is changing the state.

Comment: Let's say we have parent and child in React. The parent is passing **counter** to the child. The child has a button that says like : "Hey parent component, I'm being clicked, change counter state and let's be re-rendered." I think that what @Dai tried to clarify above. We even can do the same exact way in Angular, using **Input** and **Output** eventEmitter.

Comment: But, I think the real two-way binding data is as @possum mentioned which might be the **ngModel**.